# What is Container.DataItem exactly?

Tags: asp.net

What is Container.DataItem exactly?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[This article](http://www.jstawski.com/archive/2007/11/13/container-dataitem-what-exactly-is-this.aspx) might help you understand. Quote:

> So what is this expression exactly? The <%# %> means this is a
>   DataBinding expression and Container.DataItem is an alias for the
>   current item in the datasource. In other words, if you are binding to
>   a collection of objects Container.DataItem is the current row of that
>   collection.

[This blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2004/07/20/what-s-the-deal-with-databinder-eval-and-container-dataitem.aspx) gives help on when to use. Quote:

> Container.DataItem is a runtime alias for the DataItem for this
>   specific item in the bound list.  For a grid which displays 10 rows of
>   data, this is one row from the datasource.  The actual type of
>   DataItem is determined by the type of the datasource.  For example, if
>   the datasource is a Dataview, the type of DataItem is DataRowView.  If
>   the type of the datasource is an array of strings, the type of
>   DataItem is String.  If the datasource is a collection of
>   strongly-typed objects (for example "Employees" objects), the type of
>   DataItem is Employees.
>
> Each of these cases requires a slightly different databinding
>   expression, with further differences between VB and C#.

Comment: what does the current item in the datasource exactly mean?

Comment: @chandan - Well, if its an array of string {'a','b','c'}, then currentitem is the one which is currently processing. It could be a,b or c at that point of time. Does this answer your question?

Comment: do you mean the current item which is being processed at runtime to bind a particular dataitem from a datasource.

Comment: But what if you're trying to bind to a data source within another datasource? How can you reference specific data sources? For example I have a control bound to a sqldatasource. However, the Eval() assumes the datasource to be from the Gridview, not the control within it!

Answer (score 7):

I ran across this same question specifically in the context of trying to access `Container.DataItem` from within the code-behind. `Container` exists in the `aspx`/`ascx` code but does not exist within the code-behind. By looking at the generated C# code, I saw that it's a casted reference to `BindingContainer` on the specific control being bound.

Equivalent code-behind code for `Container.DataItem` is this:

```
var ddl = (DropDownList) source;
var dataItem = ((RepeaterItem) ddl.BindingContainer).DataItem;
```