# What's the difference between the following code when using DataBinder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I just started learning asp.net webforms and came across the problem. I am looking at Repeater control and came across this. What is the difference between the three lines of code?

```
    <%#Container.DataItem("title", "name")%>
    <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "title", "name")%>
    <%#Eval("title", "name")%>
```

Do the three produce the same output? If so, what is the difference and which should I use?
Thanks,

Comment: I'm not familiar with DataBinder, but if you want to know which you should use, perhaps you could explain what is it you want to achieve?

Comment: I am using EF. In my code behind file, I am using LINQ to retrieve data from a table. The end result should be that data should be displayed using the repeater control. title and names are the fields on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Container.DataItem(string, string)` is a single row of the datasource, its of the tipe of your LINQ query final `Select`.
2. `DataBinder.Eval` allows you to access a public property of the DataItem object. It's powerful but uses reflection at runtime so it can be really slow.
3. `Eval` is a shorthand for `DataBinder.Eval`

**References**

- [What's the difference between Databinder.Eval and Container.DataItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178863/whats-the-difference-between-databinder-eval-and-container-dataitem)
- [What is Container.DataItem exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999109/what-is-container-dataitem-exactly)
- [Asp.net forum thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1195058.aspx?Bind%20Eval%20Container%20DataItem)